# How to Disable a Certain Column in JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jtable

How can I use this code with my existing JTable from the GUI Editor.

```
    JTable table = new JTable();
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks a lot.
 Sorry I'm just newbie here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will disable every cell in the `JTable`.

```
JTable table = new JTable() {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {                
        return false;               
    };
};
```

You might want to override the method `isCellEditable` to selectively disable a particular column, like `return (column == 0)` would disable the first column.

Comment: Don't forget that the first column is column `0`.